# Very High Accuracy in Html5 Geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, augmented-reality

I'm trying to make an augmented reality game, in which the user can shoot other people who are using the web app with only their phone. The problem is, I need some way to figure out where a user is. I have thought of several ways to do this, as shown below:

- HTML5 Geolocation
- Using the Gyroscope and Accelerometer
- Somehow using XMLHttpRequest to "ping" the server and calculate position based on response time
- A combination of the last 2

So far, it's looking like I'm going to use geolocation, but the problem is it's not very accurate. I need accuracy to about a foot that updates pretty quickly. I want to do this without native iOS or Android. If needed, it can be a local thing where you have to be within a certain distance of each other, for example to connect to an access point. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 Geolocation API has an `enableHighAccuracy` option that can be turned on in addition to a `watchPosition` method that will update when the device changes location.

I've used the `enableHighAccuracy` option at work and in my experience it's usually pretty accurate within a few feet. Using it along with `watchPosition` would likely help you avoid erroneous coordinates since it updates on a set interval.

See here for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation

I can't really speak on the other methods you suggested, but I hope this was helpful.

Comment: How long does it take to update? I anticipate users moving around while using this.

Comment: From what I've seen, it generally takes a couple seconds or so. Not too terribly long. :)